# Cannot invoke HTTP DAV request. There is a pending query during OpenBinaryDirect

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-server, file

I've to move some items from one document library to an other one in a different site.
I use object client model to do this
My issue is having an exception while i'm trying to open the file and here is the exception: Cannot invoke HTTP DAV request. There is a pending query

Here is my code for copy document

```
public static void CopyDocuments(SP.ListItem doc, SP.Web srcWeb, SP.ClientContext srcContext,string srcLibrary,string destUrl, string destLibrary)
    {
        // set up the destination context
        SP.ClientContext destContext = new SP.ClientContext(destUrl);
        //destContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("SPUSER01", "SPUSER01");
        // get the new list
        SP.Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
        destContext.Load(destWeb);
        destContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Récupère l'éventuel folder
        string folderDest = doc.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString().Replace(srcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + srcLibrary, "");
        folderDest = folderDest.Substring(0, folderDest.LastIndexOf('/'));

        try
        {
            if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.File)
            {
                // get the file
                SP.File f = doc.File;
                srcContext.Load(f);
                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // build new location url
                string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + folderDest + f.Name;

                // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);//he is throw the exception
                SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);

                SP.File spfile = destWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(nLocation);
                ListItem newListItem = spfile.ListItemAllFields;
                destContext.Load(newListItem);
                destContext.ExecuteQuery();
                newListItem["Created"] = doc["Created"];
                newListItem["Created_x0020_By"] = doc["Created_x0020_By"];
                newListItem["Modified_x0020_By"] = doc["Modified_x0020_By"];
                newListItem["Modified"] = doc["Modified"];
                newListItem["Author"] = doc["Author"];
                newListItem["Editor"] = doc["Editor"];
                newListItem["Organisation_x0020_FR"] = doc["Organisation_F"];
                newListItem["Organisation_x0020_NL"] = doc["Organisation_Nl"];
                newListItem["Service_x0020_FR"] = doc["Service_x0020_Fr"];
                newListItem["Service_x0020_NL"] = doc["Service_x0020_Nl"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_Version"] = doc["Doc_x0020_Version"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_Language"] = doc["Doc_x0020_Language"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_Coordinates"] = doc["Doc_x0020_Coordinates"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_Title"] = doc["new_x0020_title"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_ID"] = doc["_dlc_DocId"];
                newListItem["Doc_x0020_Description"] = doc["Description0"];
                newListItem["Title"] = doc["Title"];
                newListItem["urlLS"] = Properties.Settings.Default.serverUrlLS + doc["FileRef"];
                newListItem.Update();
                // execute it
                List list = destContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(destLibrary);
                destContext.Load(destContext.Site);
                destContext.ExecuteQuery();

                destContext.Load(list);
                destContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
            {
                // load the folder
                srcContext.Load(doc);
                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // get the folder data, get the file collection in the folder
                SP.Folder folder = srcWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(doc.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                SP.FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;

                // load everyting so we can access it
                srcContext.Load(folder);
                srcContext.Load(fileCol);
                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
                // create the folder at the new document library if it doesn't already exist
                AddNewFolder(destUrl, destLibrary, folderDest, destLibrary, "Folder", folder.Name, doc);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.WriteError("File Error = " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if WebClient service running on the your client machine.

Comment: yes it's running and i've restarted for being sure.

Answer (score 12):

The error:

> Additional information: Cannot invoke HTTP DAV request. There is a
>   pending query.

is encountered when [ClientRuntimeContext.HasPendingRequest property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee540939.aspx) returns true.

In case of [File.OpenBinaryDirect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect.aspx) you could use the following verification:

```
if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Example**

```
private static void DownloadFile(Web web, string fileUrl,string targetPath)
{
    var ctx = (ClientContext)web.Context;
    if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    using(var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl))
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine(targetPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUrl));
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
        {
            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer works, but I do wonder what query is being executed? It is a strange - but logical - solution to a strange problem.

Comment: CSOM API stores all the queries in internal queue,  HasPendingRequest basically tells that there are queries not submitted to server yet. As far as i could guess, OpenBinaryDirect operation requires query queue to be empty